# How to set colors for the customize contours

Tags: color, legending, plotting

I am trying to beautify a contour plot where I have a wide data range. But still I want to use a linear scale for axis. But due to large range of the data, the most of the contours are restricted to a very small region. This is the reason I want to set custom contours.

The problem is, I like the color shading progression without the custom contours. As soon as I introduce custom contours this is gone. Somehow I would still like to bring the same shading back for custom contours. How should I do that?

Here is an example (but not with real data though but good enough to show)

```
 data = {{0.6994*10^-03, 0.1641*10^-02, 0.5393*10^-02, 0.1160*10^-01, 
0.2020*10^-01, 0.3113*10^-01, 0.6798*10^-01, 0.1170, 0.1760, 
0.2426, 0.3144, 0.3889, 0.4640, 0.5378, 0.6088, 0.6758, 0.7380, 
0.7948, 0.8460, 0.8915, 0.9315, 0.9661, 0.9957, 
1.021}, {0.3128*10^-03, 0.6929*10^-03, 0.2208*10^-02, 
0.4717*10^-02, 0.8199*10^-02, 0.1263*10^-01, 0.2758*10^-01, 
0.4752*10^-01, 0.7157*10^-01, 0.9877*10^-01, 0.1281, 0.1586, 
0.1894, 0.2198, 0.2490, 0.2766, 0.3022, 0.3256, 0.3467, 0.3655, 
0.3821, 0.3964, 0.4087, 0.4190}, {0.1544*10^-03, 0.3243*10^-03, 
0.1002*10^-02, 0.2125*10^-02, 0.3685*10^-02, 0.5670*10^-02, 
0.1239*10^-01, 0.2135*10^-01, 0.3219*10^-01, 0.4446*10^-01, 
0.5772*10^-01, 0.7153*10^-01, 0.8550*10^-01, 0.9926*10^-01, 
0.1125, 0.1251, 0.1368, 0.1475, 0.1572, 0.1659, 0.1735, 0.1801, 
0.1858, 0.1906}, {0.8212*10^-04, 0.1642*10^-03, 0.4920*10^-03, 
0.1035*10^-02, 0.1791*10^-02, 0.2752*10^-02, 0.6009*10^-02, 
0.1036*10^-01, 0.1563*10^-01, 0.2161*10^-01, 0.2808*10^-01, 
0.3483*10^-01, 0.4167*10^-01, 0.4842*10^-01, 0.5494*10^-01, 
0.6113*10^-01, 0.6691*10^-01, 0.7221*10^-01, 0.7702*10^-01, 
0.8133*10^-01, 0.8513*10^-01, 0.8846*10^-01, 0.9134*10^-01, 
0.9379*10^-01}, {0.4630*10^-04, 0.8852*10^-04, 0.2571*10^-03, 
0.5367*10^-03, 0.9255*10^-03, 0.1421*10^-02, 0.3099*10^-02, 
0.5346*10^-02, 0.8070*10^-02, 0.1116*10^-01, 0.1452*10^-01, 
0.1802*10^-01, 0.2158*10^-01, 0.2510*10^-01, 0.2851*10^-01, 
0.3175*10^-01, 0.3478*10^-01, 0.3758*10^-01, 0.4012*10^-01, 
0.4240*10^-01, 0.4443*10^-01, 0.4622*10^-01, 0.4777*10^-01, 
0.4910*10^-01}, {0.2735*10^-04, 0.5016*10^-04, 0.1413*10^-03, 
0.2925*10^-03, 0.5028*10^-03, 0.7708*10^-03, 0.1680*10^-02, 
0.2899*10^-02, 0.4377*10^-02, 0.6060*10^-02, 0.7886*10^-02, 
0.9799*10^-02, 0.1174*10^-01, 0.1367*10^-01, 0.1554*10^-01, 
0.1733*10^-01, 0.1900*10^-01, 0.2055*10^-01, 0.2197*10^-01, 
0.2324*10^-01, 0.2438*10^-01, 0.2539*10^-01, 0.2627*10^-01, 
0.2703*10^-01}, {0.4068*10^-06, 0.5607*10^-06, 0.1176*10^-05, 
0.2201*10^-05, 0.3630*10^-05, 0.5458*10^-05, 0.1170*10^-04, 
0.2018*10^-04, 0.3061*10^-04, 0.4267*10^-04, 0.5603*10^-04, 
0.7033*10^-04, 0.8522*10^-04, 0.1004*10^-03, 0.1156*10^-03, 
0.1305*10^-03, 0.1451*10^-03, 0.1591*10^-03, 0.1724*10^-03, 
0.1850*10^-03, 0.1969*10^-03, 0.2080*10^-03, 0.2182*10^-03, 
0.2277*10^-03}, {0.2229*10^-06, 0.2981*10^-06, 0.5990*10^-06, 
0.1101*10^-05, 0.1800*10^-05, 0.2695*10^-05, 0.5758*10^-05, 
0.9923*10^-05, 0.1506*10^-04, 0.2103*10^-04, 0.2766*10^-04, 
0.3479*10^-04, 0.4225*10^-04, 0.4988*10^-04, 0.5757*10^-04, 
0.6519*10^-04, 0.7264*10^-04, 0.7985*10^-04, 0.8677*10^-04, 
0.9336*10^-04, 0.9959*10^-04, 0.1055*10^-03, 0.1109*10^-03, 
0.1161*10^-03}};
```

With this data I am plotting as below:

```
  ListContourPlot[
  data,
  PlotRange -> All,
  Contours -> 5,
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BlueGreenYellow", "Reverse"}],
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic]
  ]
```

Since the plot is concentrated mostly in a small region I want to use some custom contours instead, like:

```
             zValues = {0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8};

   ListContourPlot[
   data,
   PlotRange -> All,
   Contours -> zValues,
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BlueGreenYellow", "Reverse"}],
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic]
   ]
```

**I want to set `Contours->zValues` but want to same color progression like `Contours->5`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the five colors from the first plot and use them as the option value for `ContourShading`:

```
lcp = ListContourPlot[data, 
   ImageSize -> Medium,
   PlotRange -> All, 
   Contours -> 5, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BlueGreenYellow", "Reverse"}], 
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic]];

colorlist = Cases[lcp[[1]], {___, clr_RGBColor, _GraphicsGroup} :> clr, All]
```

[image]

```
zValues = {0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8};

lcp2 = ListContourPlot[data, 
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Contours -> zValues, 
  ContourShading -> colorlist, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic]];

Row[{lcp, lcp2}]
```

[image]